# filesystem error: cannot create directory: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, directory, c++17

I can't believe no one seems to have posted this error or the solution. I am spinning up on C++ 17.

I am attempting to run the following code.

```
fs::directory_entry result(CodeSource::ARDUINO_SOURCE);
if (!result.exists()) {
    fs:create_directory(result);
}
return result;
```

and I get the following result.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: cannot create directory: No such file or directory [~/arduino_source]
```

The variable obviously contains "~/arduino_source" Well of course it doesn't exist. That's why I'm creating it.

The docs say it will perform as if I ran mkdir on it and so I tried it and it worked just fine.

I am running Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin I don't understand, that's what I'm doing.

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: A '~' is expanded by your shell when you use it on the command line. C++ `std::filesystem` does not use it and not aware of the existence of something called "home directory". So, it tries to find a directory called "~" in the current directory - and that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a minimal program, and confirm that it's caused by the path `~/arduino_source`, you need an absolute path or relative path, but for the tilde `~` character, it will cause exceptions.

Since the API `directory_entry::directory_entry` and `std::filesystem::create_directory` both can throw, your code needs to handle the exception to make it robust.